Getting unusual gpg error when decrypting multiple .gpg files successively in python
My python script on t2.micro ec2 instance fetches some files from an sftp server, decrypts them, and then uploads them to an s3 bucket. The problem is that occasionally when the script is running, it gives the following error when decrypting files:
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 76D10843726B51C71051CAE7FAC4CE3CE04FAD5D 0 
[GNUPG:] NO_SECKEY 4DC1246304071FA0
gpg: public key decryption failed: Wrong secret key used
[GNUPG:] ERROR pkdecrypt_failed 33545451
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_DECRYPTION
[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_FAILED
gpg: decryption failed: Wrong secret key used
[GNUPG:] END_DECRYPTION

This error does not make sense because after this error I can manually decrypt the same file on which the decryption error occurred using the same key in the terminal.
The files I download are always the same 100 files I download. The error always occurs when decrypting some random file, not the same file every time.
The only way I solved this was by adding a time.sleep(5) between each decryption. However, that is very slow so it's a problem.
Here is a minimal version of my code:
import os
import sys
import gnupg
import boto3
import json

# Function to decrypt a file and upload it to S3
def decrypt_file_and_upload(encrypted_file_path, destination_bucket, destination_key, passphrase):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    with open(encrypted_file_path, 'rb') as encrypted_file:
        decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(encrypted_file, passphrase=passphrase , always_trust=True)

    if decrypted_data.ok:
        # Upload to S3 directly
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=destination_key, Body=decrypted_data.data)
        print(f"Decrypted and uploaded {encrypted_file_path} to s3://{destination_bucket}/{destination_key}")
    else:
        print(f"Decryption failed: {decrypted_data.stderr}")

# Function to process files: decrypt and upload to S3
def download_decrypt_upload(config):
    destination_bucket = config['bucket']
    decrypted_files_dir = config['decrypt_files_folder']

    # Load passphrase from secret
    secret_name = config["secretsManager"]["gpg"]["name"]
    secret_region = config["secretsManager"]["gpg"]["region_name"]
    secrets_manager = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name=secret_region)
    secret_response = secrets_manager.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    secret_data = json.loads(secret_response["SecretString"])
    passphrase = secret_data['passphrase']

    # Decrypt and upload each encrypted file
    for file_name in os.listdir(decrypted_files_dir):
        if not file_name.endswith('.gpg'):
            continue
        encrypted_file_path = os.path.join(decrypted_files_dir, file_name)
        decrypted_file_name = file_name[:-4]  # Remove .gpg
        destination_key = f"decrypted/{decrypted_file_name}"

        decrypt_file_and_upload(encrypted_file_path, destination_bucket, destination_key, passphrase)

# Example usage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        'bucket': 'your-s3-bucket',
        'decrypt_files_folder': '/path/to/decrypted_files',
        'secretsManager': {
            'gpg': {
                'name': 'your-secret-name',
                'region_name': 'your-region'
            }
        }
    }
    download_decrypt_upload(config)


I tried passing the "default-key" argument and setting the value to my secret key in the gpg.decrypt_file function extra_args argument but that did not work.
I tried putting time.sleep(1) between each decryption but that did not work.
I tried running the decryption as a sub-process instead of using the python-gnupg library but that did not work.
Please note this error occurs occasionally, not always.

Update: The time.sleep(5) also gives error but very rarely, i had to run it a bunch of times.
